# how do I display the currently selected folder on the GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, directory

Good day,

I am using tkinter filedialog to select a folder, and to display it in the entry on the GUI?

**Here is my code so far:**

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

dir_path = ''

def inPut():
    indir = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Input Folder')
    indir = str(indir)
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(indir)
    entry.delete(0, END)
    entry.insert(0, dir_path)
    return dir_path

root = Tk()
root.geometry("640x240")
root.title("Settings")

frametop = Frame(root)
framebottom = Frame(root)
frameright = Frame(framebottom)

text = Label(frametop, text="Input Folder").grid(row=5, column=2)
entry = Entry(frametop, width=50, text=dir_path)
entry.grid(row=5,column=4,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=20)

ButtonA = Button(frametop, text="Change", command=inPut).grid(row=5, column=28)
ButtonB = Button(frameright, text="OK").grid(row=5, column=20, padx=10)

frametop.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
framebottom.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
frameright.pack(side=RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Currently, it only returns 'D:/'

1. How to make it return the full path in the entry?
2. How to change "/" to "\"
3. How do I make the app remember the folder as initial directory next time I run the app?

Please help!

Comment: What do you want to "show" for your directory? name, contents, files, folders? As for your second question: write the directory path into a file and read it on startup. if it does not exist, use a default value.

Comment: I want to show the full path selected, for example "D:\Entertainment\New Movies"                                                                                                            How do I do that? "write the directory path into a file and read it on startup"                                                                                                         Sorry, total noob here!

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve]. The code above would return unrelated error(s) as opposed to the claimed behavior. Please fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write it into your Label you need to have a reference to it.

multiple possibilities:

1. create a class for your GUI and use `showdir` or a textvariable bound to it as instance variable
2. pass a reference to your call to have `showdir` available
3. global `showdir`

why this order? most to least preferrable.

If you do not know how to write to or read from a file, start with python tutorials before you start creating GUIs. There is no point in "puzzling together code that someone else wrote" if you do not know why you do certain steps as you do them. Its like driving a car without knowing what traffic is.

As to your **edit**:

your code does work now as you do not access the property directly anylonger so you don't use immediate write access to entry.

- `return dir_path` is completely obsolete.
- you do not get the folder as your `os.path.dirname(indir)` returns - as per definition inside the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) the path of the parent directory. If you used a file instead of a directory dirname would be okay, as long as you use a directory, use `os.path.abspath`.

> os.path.dirname(path)¶
>
> Return the directory name of pathname path. This is the first element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split().

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer isn't helpfull at all, your telling me something that I already know, I know I need a reference...did you look at my code?              showdir = Label(frametop, text = dirtext).grid(row=5, column=21)

Comment: obviously not - your reference needs to be accessible. objects used inside a function need to be available inside that scope. you can read variables from the global scope inside a function but to write to them you need to either pass their reference, have them accessible as being an instance variable or declare them global inside your function, just as i told you inside my answer.

Comment: I shortened the code and managed to get it to show the drive letter, please see above

Comment: I adjusted the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked 100% But how to save the directory so that it's there when the app is closed and opened again? (Which is what the "OK" button is for)